# strange behaviour of TemporalData

Tags: bugs, time-series

**Bug persisting through 11.2.0**

---

For example, we have

```
v = {10, 100};
u = {20, 2000};
t = {1, 2};
```

Then I construct two TemporalData

```
td1=TemporalData[{v,u},{t}]
td2=TemporalData[{v,u},-{t}]
```

I call `td2` is reversed relative to `td1`, and

```
td1 // Normal
td2 // Normal
```

gives

```
{{{1, 10}, {2, 100}}, {{1, 20}, {2, 2000}}}
{{{-2, 100}, {-1, 10}}, {{-2, 2000}, {-1, 20}}}
```

**Now comes the peculiar part:**

first, obviously

```
{v, u} === td1["ValueList"]
t === td1["Times"]
```

gives

```
True
True
```

However,

```
TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {td1["Times"]}] === td1
TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}] === td2
```

gives

```
True
False
```

What?! **They suppose to be both true. Why the second identity is false?**

I tried to `Trace`, but even as simple as `TemporalData[{1}, {{1}}]//Trace` will produce huge bulk of result, don't know what is going on there.

By the way, I also tried

```
Activate[Inactive[TemporalData][
   td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]] === td2
```

Also `False`.

**So How can I create a function that serves to reverse `TemporalData`?** **The function below is not working, why?**

```
Clear[reverseTemporalData];
reverseTemporalData[temporalData_] := 
 Module[{valueList = temporalData["ValueList"], 
   times = temporalData["Times"]},
  TemporalData[valueList, -{times}]]

reverseTemporalData[td1]===td2
(*False*)
```

PS. I am using *Mathematica* 11.2

Comment: Looks like a bug/feature: it seems that you need to `Reverse` the values when you minus the times: `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {-td1["Times"]}]==TemporalData[Reverse/@{v, u}, {-t}]` gives `True`.

Comment: @kglr But How to understand `TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]===td2` give True?

Comment: @kglr  and `Clear[reverseTemporalData];
reverseTemporalData[temporalData_] := 
 Module[{valueList = temporalData["ValueList"], 
   times = temporalData["Times"]},
  TemporalData[Reverse /@ valueList, {-times}]]` doesn't work

Comment: maybe `ClearAll[rubeGoldbergReverseTimesInTemporalData];
 rubeGoldbergReverseTimesInTemporalData[t_TemporalData] :=TemporalData[ Reverse /@ Transpose[Reverse@Transpose@t["ValueList"]], {-t["Times"]}];rubeGoldbergReverseTimesInTemporalData[td1] ===td2`?:)

Comment: Thank you@kglr. Your rubeGoldbergReverseTimesInTemporalData version works. But I think we can not trust rubeGoldbergReverseTimesInTemporalData in the future. Because it is using bug to work around bug. We must uncover what is going on with the bug : ) For example, your first comment `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {-td1["Times"]}]==TemporalData[Reverse/@{v, u}, {-t}]` is actually not an expected result according to the definition of TemporalData. According to the definition, `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]` shoud be equal to `TemporalData[{v, u}, {-t}]`

Comment: @kglr I found a probably better work around `TemporalData[reverseTemporalData /@ td1["Components"]]`. Because I found my `reverseTemporalData ` works for one dimensional temporaldata

Comment: This also seems to work: `TemporalData[Uncompress@Compress@td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}] === td2` - for some reason, destroying the "identity" of the value list helps `TemporalData` to behave properly...

Comment: matheorem, that sounds like a good self-answer.

Comment: @Mathe172 Interesting observation. +1

Comment: @kglr  Still waiting some explanation : )

Answer (score 6):

Here's what's going on

```
TemporalData[Developer`FromPackedArray@td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}] === td2
(* True *)
```

This is definitely a bug, and I have forward this to the relevant developers.  My understanding is that the fact that first argument is packed is tricking the code into thinking the values are already sorted, even though they need to be re-sorted because the times have been reversed.

Comment: Hi, @Itai Seggev. Thank you for explanation. But I don't quite understand the "re-sorted" procedure, could you explain a little why it needs resorting? What is more, I don't understand why `Normal@Activate[
  Inactive[TemporalData][td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]]` is not equal to `Normal@TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]`. It seems that it is consistent with functionality of `Inactive` and `Activate`

Comment: As for your second question, `Activate[ Inactive[TemporalData][td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]]` is exactly equivalent to `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {{-1, -2}}]` and so this the same as above.  Why would you expect inactivating and then activating somehow alter the behavior?

Comment: As for your first, note that `td1["ValueList"]` and `td2["ValueList"]` are different.  It needs to decide whether it has been given in the form of "ValueList" or tranposed, and is making different decisions based on whether the array is packed or not.

Comment: Hi, @Itai Seggev. Thank you for explanation. But `Normal@TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]` gives different result from `Normal@TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {{-1, -2}}]`.  If you run `Inactive[TemporalData][td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]`, it is gives `Inactive[TemporalData][{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]`. Why you said it is equivalent to `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {{-1, -2}}]`?

Comment: That's not what I said.  If you evaluate the two expressions I entered, you'll find they product exactly the same result as I claim.  You are missing the point that `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {{-1, -2}}] === 
 TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]` gives `False`, even though `td1["ValueList"] === {{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}` gives `True`.  `Activate` & `Inactive` have nothing to do with the issue at hand.  This is resolved by the fact that ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {td1["ValueList"], {{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}}`` gives `{True,False}` (still a bug, but explains what's going on).

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation. forgive my slow comprehession : )  I know that `TemporalData[td1["ValueList"], {{-1, -2}}] === TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]` gives `False`. But my point is that since `Inactive[TemporalData][td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]` is evaluated to `Inactive[TemporalData][{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]`, then `Normal@Activate[ Inactive[TemporalData][td1["ValueList"], -{td1["Times"]}]]` should be equivalent to `Normal@TemporalData[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}, {{-1, -2}}]`. But they are not equal. This confuse me.

Comment: Well,  `td1["ValueList"]` also evaluates to `{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}`, so this is really the same question.  It is all due to the fact that packed arrays are supposed to be "tranparent" to other functions.  So both  `{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}` and  ``Developer`ToPackedArray[{{10, 100}, {20, 2000}}]`` format the same, but they are different expressions.  The output from `td1["ValueList"]` is the latter, so any expression where you explictly type in the matrix (without also adding the `ToPackedArray`) will be a different input.  The bug is that it should give the same result, and it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, I was so stupid. I finally understand what you mean. Thank you so much for your patient explanation : )